# What percentage of binary digits in $\frac{a}{b}$ are ones?

Tags: binary, totient-function

Not too long ago, with the aid of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086591/for-any-odd-number-n-does-there-always-exist-k-such-that-2k-1-is-a-mult), I was able to deduce that for any natural number $b$, the binary representation of $\frac{1}{b}$ will have a cycle of repeating digits of length $\phi(b)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's [Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). The digits that repeat are the same sequence of digits as are found in the terminating $\frac{2^{\phi(b)}-1}{b}$.

For example, $\frac{1}{9}=0.\overline{000111}_{(2)}$. The cycle is of length $\phi(9)=6$, and the sequence of repeating digits are $\frac{2^{\phi(9)}-1}{9}=7=111_{(2)}$.

Hence, we can calculate that the "percentage" of digits that are ones in the binary expansion of $\frac{1}{b}$ as $$\frac{H\left(\frac{2^{\phi(b)}-1}{b}\right)}{\phi(b)}. \text{E,g; for }b=9:\ \frac{H(7)}{6}=\frac{3}{6}=50\%$$
where $H$ is the [Hamming Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight).

How can we extend this to calculate the "percentage" (for lack of a better term) of digits that are ones in the binary expansion of any rational number $\frac{a}{b}$, and not just the reciprocals of the natural numbers?

Comment: You mean $\frac{H\left(\frac{2^{\phi(b)}-1}{b}\right)}{\phi(b)}$?

Comment: @razivo Yes! Thank you for spotting that. Should be fixed.

Comment: Surely it’s just $H(a\cdot (2^{\phi(b)}-1)/b) / \phi(b)$?  The argument of $H$ is smaller than $2^{\phi(b)}$, for $a<b$, and so has no more than $\phi(b)$ binary digits.

Comment: "cycle of repeating digits length $\phi(b)$" Nicely worded, avoiding using the word period since the actual period can be shorter than this. For example $\phi(17)=16$, and while $1/17$ indeed repeats every 16 bits, its actual period happens to be only 8 bits.

Comment: You should specify that $b$ is odd in order to get the assertions in your first paragraph.

Comment: @GEdgar, it still works for even numbers, it's just that $\frac{2^{\phi(b)}-1}{b}$ won't be a whole number, but will still have the same sequence of binary digits (excluding the radix point) as repeat in $\frac{1}{b}.$